# newSingleThreadExecutor make thread keep values ( android )

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am developing an android app with java and for some repetitive task I am going to use newSingleThreadExecutor.

However I wish this newSingleThreadExecutor keeps some information saved within itself.

For example

```
public class adder implements Runnable {
    int count;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        count++; 
    }
}
```

I want to post this sort of task 
but I know that the value of count won't be kept if I create a new instance of that runnable every time i post that task,

So my first question is

1. can I use the same Runnable instance multiple times..? is this safe?

However even if this could be the solution, I really don't prefer putting all the important variables as a member of a single Runnable Class so I am trying to make the thread update some static or instance variables (heap) and make them keep the values that the worker thread has updated.

For example

```
public class adder implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        GlobalState.count++; 
    }
}
```

but I learned that  when a thread updates a non local variable it my not be directly updated to the main memory unless it is declared volatile, and I also learned that a thread made by newSingleThreadExecutor can be destroyed if the thread didn't get any work for a long time so I'm worried the values that the thread has updated don't get saved properly to the main memory before it gets destroyed. so my second question is

2. when threads are destroyed , is it guaranteed that all of the non local, heap variables that have been modified by the thread updated to the main memory?

Comment: Write a custom AsyncTask, that's what they're for.

Comment: well but, aren't AsyncTasks for communicating with the UI thread? I think that is quite redundant.. I just want the worker thread to keep some state variables. of course what you said indeed is a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question**: Yes, the Runnable instance can be reused in another Thread. It's just a class which implements the run() method, latter will be called by new Thread( myRunnable).start(). Theoretically you even may run the same Runnable in parallel by different threads, but this would not make sense at all.

**Second question**: If your GlobalState.count variable is declared as volatile I would assume that it is indeed stored to the heap immediately (or more precise: It will be updated to the correct value in the used L1, L2 and L3 caches at least when some other thread accesses it).

Since differnt threads increment the global variable you should add some synchronization, either

```
synchronized( GlobalState.class) { GlobalState.count++}
```

*or* implement a synchronized incrementCount() in the GlobalState class

*or* use AtomicInteger to be sure that an operation on the variable is performed atomic within one thread.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, However I'm still wondering, if the GlobalState.count variable is NOT declared volatile, it is possible that a modification made by the worker thread can be ignored forever ? even when the worker thread is destroyed?